Does the conditional expectation operator have an interpretable decomposition like the projection matrix does in linear algebra?
I'm trying to draw a parallel between the concept of projections in a finite linear space to an infinite linear space.
Here is the set-up, first in the finite dimensional case, and then second in the infinite dimensional case:
Given an injective matrix, $A: \mathbb{R}^m \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$, we can construct an orthogonal projection operator by letting $P_A = A(A^\top A)^{-1}A^\top$. Then we can use this to take $y \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and project it onto the column-space of $A$ to get $P_A y = x \in \text{col(A)}$.
Now suppose that we have two random variables $X$ and $Y$ whose second moments exist. The conditional expectation $\mathbb{E}[X\mid Y]$ gives us some new random variable $h(Y)$ that is the orthogonal projection of $X$ onto $\sigma(Y)$, the sigma algebra of $Y$.
My question is if there is an interpretable analog to $A$ in the conditional expectation case. That is, $\mathbb{E}[X\mid Y]$ is to $P_A$ as [???] is to $A$.
I saw that the user ExcitedSnail asked a very similar question here, but the comments underneath the question didn't seem to address the question, unless I just misunderstood.

@Sextus My understanding is that if $X \in L^2(\mathcal{F}, \mu)$ where $\mathcal{F}$ is a sigma-algebra and $\mu$ is a probability measure, then the conditional expectation of X wrt a sub-sigma-algebra $\mathcal{G} \subset\mathcal{F}$ is the orthogonal projection of $X$ onto the linear subspace $L^2(\mathcal{G}, \mu)$.
For us, X is being projected onto the space of $\sigma(Y)$-measurable RVs.
This can be verified from the facts that $\mathbb{E}[X|Y]$ must be $\sigma(Y)$-measurable and that $\mathbb{E}[Y[X - \mathbb{E}[X|\sigma(Y)]]] = 0$.
Please let me know if anything is incorrect.

@Sextus Sorry, I wasn't sure if it was unclear because of a mistake on my part. Let me back up.
In linear algebra, we can take a set of vectors and call it a vector space if it satisfies the vector space axioms.
Here, instead of the elements being vectors in the space $\mathbb{R}^n$, the elements are functions in the space $L^2(\mu)$. Here, $L^2(\mu)$ refers to the set of functions that are square integrable wrt the measure $\mu$.
That is, for $X$ to be in $L^2$, we require $\int X^2 d\mu < \infty$.

@Sextus So for a probability example, if $X$ is distributed according to the t-distribution with 2 degrees of freedom, then our measure $\mu$ is $f(x) dx$, the pdf of $X$.
In this case, $X \notin L^2(\mu)$, as the second moment of $X$ does not exist; $\int x^2  f(x) dx$ is not integrable.
However, we can say that $X$ is in another space, namely $L^1$, as the first moment of $X$ exists. If $X$ was distributed as a t-distribution with 3 or more degrees of freedom, then $X$ would live in $L^2(\mu)$.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

@Sextus Respectfully, the question was aimed at people who already have an understanding of the connections between probability theory and functional analysis. I'm not sure if this is the place to be asking these questions. If you're interested in how the conditional expectation can be seen as an orthogonal projection, perhaps see chapter 10 of Resnick's "A Probability Path" or chapter 3 of Bobrowski's "Functional Analysis for Probability and Stochastic Processes".

@Sextus It's not possible for a question to be accessible to every user, and so unfortunately a line has to be drawn. I'm happy to explain some of the ideas behind the post, but again, the character limit of the comments section makes it difficult to provide the necessary background since it sounds like you are not familiar with measure theoretic concepts (which is fine, it just requires more context). If you have specific questions, I'm happy to try to answer them in the chatroom I opened.

At the outset, there's nothing special about $A$ in $ P_A.$
To briefly (over)simplify, the concept of orthogonal projection stems from the necessity of finding the "closest" point of an element in a certain suitable space.
Formally,
Result $ 1:$ Let $\mathscr A$ be a closed, convex subset (e.g. closed subspace) of a Hilbert space $(\mathbb H, \Vert \cdot\Vert),$ where $\Vert \cdot\Vert$ is a unitary norm. If $x\in\mathbb H, $ then there exists a unique element $\tilde a\in\mathscr A$ such that $$\Vert x-\tilde a\Vert =\inf_{a\in\mathscr A}\Vert x-a\Vert.\tag 1\label 1$$
Result $2:$ There exists a self-adjoint linear operator $\mathbf P$ on $\mathbb H$ such that $\mathbf P^2=\mathbf P,~\operatorname{range}(\mathbf P) =\mathscr A$ and $$\langle x-\mathbf Px, a\rangle =0 ~~\forall a\in\mathscr A. \tag 2\label 2$$
These results are the underlying principles whenever one is working on "best approximation, best mean square predictor" etc: the former one ensures the existence of a unique "closest point" while the latter that of projection operator. In fact, Result $2$ characterizes the projection operator onto a certain subspace.
(I am not showing the proofs as they are standard results and can be found in the references below; for the sake of completeness, the first one is based on the Cauchy criterion of completeness and continuity of inner product and the second one simply on elementary minimization technique).
To see where OP's $P_A$ comes from, one my note that when the Hilbert space $\mathbb H:= \mathbb R^n$ and $\mathscr A:=\overline{\operatorname{sp}}\{\mathbf x_1,\ldots,\mathbf x_m\},$ then if $\mathbf X:=(\mathbf x_j)_{j=1}^m $ is non-singular, $$\mathbf P_\mathscr A\mathbf x = \mathbf X\left(\mathbf X^\top \mathbf X\right) ^{-1}\mathbf X^\top \mathbf x. \tag 3\label 3$$
$\eqref 3$ follows from $\eqref 2:$ since $\mathbf P_\mathscr A\mathbf x\in\mathscr A, $ for some $\boldsymbol\beta\in\mathbb R^m, $ $$\mathbf P_\mathscr A\mathbf x= \mathbf X\boldsymbol\beta,$$ and by $\eqref 2,$ we are able to write for all $ j\in \{1,\ldots,m\},$ $$\langle \mathbf x-\mathbf X\boldsymbol\beta,\mathbf x_j\rangle =0.\tag 4\label 4$$ $\eqref 4$ leads to the familiar normal equations $\mathbf X^\top \mathbf X\boldsymbol\beta=\mathbf X^\top\mathbf x $ from which $\eqref 3$ is evident.
Now consider $\mathbb H:= L^2(\Omega, \boldsymbol{\mathfrak F}, \mathbb P)$ with $\langle X, Y\rangle:=\int_\Omega XY~\mathrm d\mathbb P=\mathbf E(XY). $ If $\boldsymbol{\mathfrak G}$ is a sub–$\sigma$–algebra of $\boldsymbol{\mathfrak F}, $ then $\mathscr A:= L^2(\Omega, \boldsymbol{\mathfrak G}, \mathbb P)$ is a closed linear subspace. Rewinding the same story above, we can see the conditional expectation of $X\in \mathbb H$ given $\mathscr A$ is the projection of $X$ onto $\mathscr A, $ that is, $$\mathbf E(X\mid \mathscr A) =\mathbf P_\mathscr A X. \tag 5\label 5$$
To digest $\eqref 5,$ perhaps the simplest example is when $\Omega =\bigsqcup_{i=1}^m B_i, ~B_i\in\boldsymbol{\mathfrak F}, ~\mathscr A:=\sigma(B_i,~i=\{1,\ldots,m\}).$ Then the conditional expectation of $X:= \boldsymbol 1_A,~A\in\boldsymbol{\mathfrak F}$ with respect to $\mathscr A$ is of the form $Y:=\sum_{i=1}^mb_i\boldsymbol 1_{B_i}$ where $\langle b_i\rangle_{i=1}^m$ are found by minimizing $\mathbf E\vert Y-X\vert^2;$ it's easy to check $b_i$ turns out to be $\mathbb P(A\mid B_i). $
So, in a nutshell, in the quest of finding the "closest point", we utilize the first two results, as $\mathbb H, ~\mathscr A$ vary. OP's two different projections are united by the same principles but with different structures.

Appendix:
Tbh, conditional expectation is defined in $L^1(\Omega, \boldsymbol{\mathfrak F}, \mathbb P)$ as a Markov operator $\mathbf P_\mathscr A$ in that if $X\in L^1(\Omega, \boldsymbol{\mathfrak F}, \mathbb P),~\mathscr A\subset \boldsymbol{\mathfrak A}$ a sub–$\sigma$–algebra, the conditional expectation $\mathbf P_\mathscr A: X\to \mathbf E(X\mid \mathscr A) $ preserves all the functionals $X\mapsto \int_{A\in\mathscr A} X~\mathrm d\mathbb P, $ that is, $$\int_{A} X~\mathrm d\mathbb P=\int_A\mathbf P_\mathscr AX~\mathrm d\mathbb P. \tag 6\label 6$$
Result $3.$ When restricted to $L^2(\Omega, \boldsymbol{\mathfrak F}, \mathbb P),$ the Markov operator $\mathbf P_\mathscr A$ becomes a projection operator onto $L^2(\Omega, \boldsymbol{\mathfrak G}, \mathbb P).$
$\eqref 6$ follows from $\eqref 2$ as for $X\in L^2(\Omega, \boldsymbol{\mathfrak F}, \mathbb P),~\langle X-\mathbf P_\mathscr A X, Z\rangle = 0$ for all $Z\in L^2(\Omega, \boldsymbol{\mathfrak G}, \mathbb P)$ and subsequently taking $Z:=\mathbf 1_A.$ Since $L^2(\Omega, \boldsymbol{\mathfrak F}, \mathbb P)$ is linearly dense in $L^1(\Omega, \boldsymbol{\mathfrak F}, \mathbb P),~\mathbf P_\mathscr A$ can be extended to $L^1(\Omega, \boldsymbol{\mathfrak F}, \mathbb P), $ provided $\mathbf P_\mathscr A X\geq 0$ whenever $X\in L^2(\Omega, \boldsymbol{\mathfrak F}, \mathbb P)$ is non-negative (cf. $\rm[I,~2.3.37]$). To see that, assume, on the contrary, $\mathbb P\{\omega\in\Omega\mid \mathbf P_\mathscr A X(\omega)<0\}\ne 0.$ Then for some $n\in\mathbb N, ~\mathbb P\left\{\omega\in\Omega\mid \mathbf P_\mathscr AX(\omega)<-\frac1n\right\}=\delta>0,$say. Then on this subset, by $\eqref 6,$
$$0<\int X~\mathrm d\mathbb P=\int \mathbf P_\mathscr AX~\mathrm d\mathbb P<-\frac{\delta}{n}, \tag 7\label 7$$ which is a contradiction.
$\blacksquare$
--
References:
$\rm[I]$ Functional Analysis for Probability and Stochastic Processes: An Introduction, Adam Bobrowski, CUP, $2005, $ sec. $2.3, 3.1-3.3.$
$\rm[II]$ Time Series: Theory and Methods, Peter J. Brockwell, Richard A. Davis, Springer Science$+$Business, $2006, $ sec. $2.3, 2.5,2.7.$

In result 1, please use "e.g." in place of "i.e.": closed convex subsets are far more general than closed subspaces!

Of course these are not same! Thanks for pointing out @whuber.

@User1865345 Thanks for your well-written answer, but I'm unsure what the conclusion is. Are you saying that there is not an interpretable analog because even though these projections come about from the same principles, their constructions cannot be (easily) thought of as 1-to-1 parallels?

@absolutelyzeroEQ, the construction is same based on the principles as you noted. The spaces changed. The interpretation should be based on finding the "closest" point belonging to a space from a given point.

@User1865345 Then I am still having trouble understanding what the analog to the injective matrix $A$ is (if any) in the conditional expectation case.

I think this is very interesting. Is it somehow related to the Mori-Zwanzig projection formalism in statistical physics? https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mori-Zwanzig_formalism if you look in the article you will find a projection operator, but I am not completely sure if it is related ...

@absolutelyzeroEQ $A$ would be equivalent to $\sigma(Y) $ in your terminology. That is, the spaces, the element is projected on.

@User1865345 Hmmm, I'll need to spend some time to digest that. I understand what you're saying, but to me, it seems like $\sigma(Y)$ would be analogous to $\text{col}(A)$, the column space of $A$. I understand that $\text{col}(A)$ and $A$ represent the same space, but to me it still feels like there is a distinction there.
In other words, could I not find another matrix $A'$ such that $A' \ne A$, but $\text{col}(A') = \text{col}(A)$?

Exactly. If you follow my answer, that would be affirmative. I am indeed talking about $\operatorname{col}(A). $

@User1865345 I may have not been totally clear with my question then. Given the linear map $A$, I can "build" the operator $P$. Can I "build" the operator $\mathbb{E}[X | Y]$ from some linear mapping relating to $Y$?

Without further specifications of what $Y$ is, the general statement would be that you can. But how and whether that would be easy or difficult again depend on the space. However the recipe remains same @absolutelyzeroEQ.

@absolutelyzeroEQ Long story short, one cannot define (or deduce) $E[X|Y]$ explicitly in a closed-form in terms of $Y$ (unless $(X, Y)$ has a special distribution, say normal).  It is defined by the integral equation (6) in the answer.

On the other hand, you still can interpret it as a projection to some functional space in that it minimizes the $L^2$ distance, which is the key characteristic of a "projection", shared by other scenarios where $P$ has a closed-form expression. Therefore, the correct analogy you should make is between $P_\mathscr{A}$ and $P_A$, instead of between [???] (which is impossible) and $A$.

@Zhanxiong Right, I think I understand the analogy between $P_{\mathscr{A}}$ and $P_{A}$. They are both orthogonal projections of an element of a space onto a subspace. $P_A u = v$ is to $\mathbb{E}[X | Y] = f(Y)$, where $P_A$ is sending $u$ onto the column space of $A$ to get $v$, and $\mathbb{E}[X | Y]$ is sending $X$ onto the space of $\sigma(Y)$-measurable functions to get $f(Y)$.
So it sounds like the answer is: No, there is not an easily interpretable analog to $A$ in the conditional expectation case.
Although you mention that there is in the Gaussian case. What would that be?

@absolutelyzeroEQ Yes, your summary is right.  For the Gaussian case, suppose $$(X, Y) \sim N_2\left(\begin{bmatrix} \mu_1 \ \mu_2 \end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix} \sigma_1^2 & \rho\sigma_1\sigma_2 \ \rho\sigma_1\sigma_2 & \sigma_2^2\end{bmatrix}\right),$$ then $$E[X|Y] = \mu_1 + \rho\sigma_1\sigma_2^{-1}(Y - \mu_2).$$ That is, $E[X|Y]$ in Gaussian case is a linear function of $Y$.

@absolutelyzeroEQ, reading your comments, I would admit you know all the facts you need and have somewhat arranged them chronologically. Coming to your last query, while I agree with Zhanxiong (in fact, that was what I have been saying), I would state if it is really necessary to make some sort of analog, $\operatorname{col}(A) $ would be in tandem with the $L^2$ space generated by $\sigma(Y). $ The interpretable analog, to me, seems to be subjective. But what is robust is the fact that like the $\mathrm R^n$ counterpart, conditional expectation also is a projection operator, [ctd]

doing the same thing a typical projection operator does (of course, in general, it's a Markov operator). @absolutelyzeroEQ

Sure @Zhanxiong, the Gaussian example is the one classical example that has its house set :-)

@SextusEmpiricus, unfortunately I am not sure what projection means in your commentary.


Does the conditional expectation operator have an interpretable decomposition like the projection matrix does in linear algebra?

In the simple case of a finite sample space, then real variables are functions $f:\Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ that can be expressed as points in the space $\mathbb{R}^n$ where each coordinate is the value of the mapping.
Then this question has an easy interpretable analogy between 'the conditional expectation operator' and 'the projection matrix in linear algebra'. And the conditional expectation can be directly described in terms of a weighted OLS regression
$$E[X|Y] = A(A^TWA)^{-1}A^TWX$$
where $X$ is a vector relating to the random variable and each element in the vector is the function value in the mapping of a sample to a real value $f:\Omega \to \mathbb{R}$. Here $A$ is a matrix with rows for each sample $\omega$ and columns for each possible value $y$ of the variable $Y$ and the entries are equal to $A_{ij} = \mathbb{1}_{f(\omega_i) =  y_j}$ it is equal to one if the $i$-th sample maps to the $j$-the variable value and it is zero otherwise. The weights $W$ relate to the probability measure relating to each sample.
An example is made in comments and answer to the referenced question How is conditional expectation related to projection?

My question is if there is an interpretable analog to $A$ in the conditional expectation case. That is, $\mathbb{E}[X\mid Y]$ is to $P_A$ as [???] is to $A$.

The analog of $A$ is the generating  set of events for the of $Y$. $A_{ij} = \mathbb{1}_{\omega_i \in y_j}$
For a finite space the analogy is similar but now the finite dimensional space $\mathbb{R}^n$ is a  Hilbert space.
Example

If we have a uniform probability mass for samples $(z_1,z_2) \in [0,1]^2$. Then we can imagine any real valued variable as a function $f:(z_1,z_2) \to \mathbb{R}$ that maps a point $(z_1,z_2)$ to a real value.
When  we consider expectation values in some variable, e.g. $Y = z_1+z_2$, then this reduces the potential variables to a space of functions that are solely of the form $f:(z_1+z_2) \to \mathbb{R}$. (Now the mapping is only for the sum $z_1+z_2$, and samples $(z_1,z_2)$ with the same sum will map to the same value.

The role of $Y$ is to define a subspace onto which a projection is made.

What is a "conditional random variable $Z|Y$"?  In probability, there are no objects of "$X|Y$" or "$Z|Y$".

Not nitpicking, the correctness of stating $X|Y = y \sim N(y, \sigma^2)$ (i.e., to discuss the conditional distribution of $X$ given $Y$) does not make it OK to call "$X|Y$" a random variable.  Also see my comments under this post.

What do the columns and rows of this A matrix represent, exactly?

I'm not sure how this answers the question, which is specifically about relating the finite dimensional case to the infinite dimensional case. You've seemed to show here that the unconditioned expectation is like a projection onto the "constant" space, which is like projecting onto the one vector.

@Sextus It's quite literally the very first sentence of the post. "I'm trying to draw a parallel between the concept of projections in a finite linear space to an infinite linear space."

@Sextus "the title, the link to the other question, everything else in the post is without the idea of projections in infinite space." Yes, if you remove the part of the post that indicates that I am interested specifically in the infinite dimensional case, there is nothing that indicates that I am interested specifically in the infinite dimensional case. That's why I added the sentence. I know that a conditional expectation is a function of the variable being conditioned upon, and that if $\sigma(X) \subset \sigma(Y)$, the conditional expectation is just X itself. Why are you telling me this?

@absolutelyzeroEQ simplifying the question helps to understand it and get an intuition for the more complex case. A part of the question seems to ask for an analogy between the projection $E[X|Y]$ and the projection $P_A$. At least for finite sample spaces the two can be easily seen as an analoguos, and that is a step forward. Then the question is not anymore about the analogy between $E[X|Y]$ and $P_A$, but instead only about the step to infinite dimension.

You ask "My question is if there is an interpretable analog to A in the conditional expectation case." and that is what I attempted to answer. I only simplified it to finite dimensions.
